# Node.js - Perfect elastic collision detection and reaction between circle and rectangle

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, physics

I'm currently making a game where I need to check collision between circle and rectangle, where the circle can be bigger than the rectangle, but also the opposite, then make them react. They can also be static or moving.

For now, I have this code:

```js
// Check if b1 is a rectangle and b2 a circle
if (!b1.collisionRadius && b2.collisionRadius) {
  if (Physics.circleRectangleCollision(b1, b2)) {
    b1.collision = b2.uid;
    b2.collision = b1.uid;

    if(b1.isStatic) {}
    else if(b2.isStatic) {}
    else {}
    // Collision reaction
  }
}

// Physics.circleRectangleCollision
circleRectangleCollision(rect, circle) {
  var distx = Math.abs(circle.position.x - rect.position.x);
  var disty = Math.abs(circle.position.y - rect.position.y);

  if (distx > (rect.width / 2 + circle.collisionRadius)) { return false; }
  if (disty > (rect.height / 2 + circle.collisionRadius)) { return false; }

  if (distx <= (rect.width / 2)) { return true; }
  if (disty <= (rect.height / 2)) { return true; }

  var hypot = (distx - rect.width / 2) * (distx - rect.width / 2) +
    (disty - rect.height / 2) * (disty - rect.height / 2);

  return (hypot <= (circle.collisionRadius * circle.collisionRadius));
}
```

(code) https://glitch.com/edit/#!/demostanis-worlds-physics-engine

What should I do for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you readed phisics articles how this should behave. Do you got it in pictures/animations? can U provide working code example ???

Comment: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/demostanis-worlds-physics-engine